# Only Returning Filenames with Unique String in PHP

Tags: php

I'm getting xml files generated daily and renamed to a specific structure like as follows:

```
03-17-2017 02 05 09 PM - (20000) - Item 1.xml
03-17-2017 02 06 14 PM - (20001) - Item 2.xml
03-17-2017 02 06 19 PM - (20002) - Item 3.xml
03-17-2017 02 08 03 PM - (20003) - Item 4.xml
03-17-2017 02 08 53 PM - (20004) - Item 5.xml
03-17-2017 02 09 41 PM - (20002) - Item 3.xml
```

As you can see, I sometimes get duplicates, such as `20002`, with a different timestamp.

Is there a way to programatically exclude this and only include unique numbers in my retrieval? The filename structure is always the same and the number is always a 6 digit number.

Right now I am using [glob](http://php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php) to return the files in the directory

```
$files = glob("03-17-2017/*.xml");

if (is_array($files)) {

foreach($files as $filename) {

//

}
```

Is there a function or method in being selective to only retrieve the filenames with a unique number?

Comment: I would say use [`array_filter()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) from your glob and grab that substring from the filename and check whether it's in an array that you `use`. Then you `return true` if you want to keep the row and `return false` if you don't.

Comment: *the number is always a 6 digit number.* - you meant 5, I suppose

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two approaches to get the needed result:

-- using `strpos` and `substr` functions:

```
$files = [];
foreach (glob("03-17-2017/*.xml") as $f) {
    $start_pos = strpos($f, "(") + 1;
    $num = substr($f, $start_pos, strpos($f, ')') - $start_pos);
    if (!isset($files[$num])) $files[$num] = $f;
}

print_r($files);
```

---

-- using `preg_match` function:

```
$files = [];
foreach (glob("03-17-2017/*.xml") as $f) {
    preg_match("/\((\d{5})\)/", $f, $m);    // capturing the number
    $num = $m[1];
    if (!isset($files[$num])) $files[$num] = $f;
}
```

Comment: Works great! Really smart approaches will have to look into its functionality more.

Comment: Really like how the first one just captures the numbers between the ( ) regardless of the digits.  Did not even think of that.